# fancybox u is undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, fancybox

I have made this script to open a fancybox from code behind, but it keeps saying "u is undefined"... not sure what's wrong

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("<script>");
sb.AppendLine("$.fancybox('../Popups/EndedProduction.aspx?Iframe', {");
sb.AppendLine("'width': 557,");
sb.AppendLine("'height': 244,");
sb.AppendLine("'transitionIn': 'none',");
sb.AppendLine("'transitionOut': 'none'");
sb.AppendLine("});");
sb.AppendLine("</script>");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Completed", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way around it.

```
<a id="popup" href="../Popups/EndedProduction.aspx?Iframe"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            $("#popup").fancybox({
                'width': 557,
                'height': 244,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'type': 'iframe'
            });
        }

<% if (Current.Production.Status >= (Int32)ProductionStatus.Completed)
{ %>
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#popup").fancybox().trigger('click');
      });

   <%} %>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the generated source of the document(for example with HTML-tab in firebug) and be sure that you didn't embed the fancybox-script twice.

Comment: all I got on the page that have anything to do with fancybox is:<link href="../Modules/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="../Modules/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../Modules/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Modules/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I was setting up a function like what is posted in your original question, encountered the same error, and when I used the unpacked source the parameter was the "loading" var.  A lot of stack overflow answers suggest this happens when the Flexbox script is loaded twice, but in my case it wasn't.  The answer was simply wrapping the FancyBox call in jQuery(document).ready.  Your solution does this but eliminates the original manual trigger, so I'm curious if this would have solved your problem.